# Building a golang struct to store data from parsed JSON file

Tags: json, go, struct, unmarshalling

I'm trying to load a rather large JSON file that has x amount of JSON arrays. The issue I'm having is the fact that the each node in the data below has a unique name, so I'm not sure how to build the struct to store them.

Here is snippet of the data from the JSON file (This file can have many more nodes that just two below)

```
       {
            "timestamp": 1533397325,
            "total_nodes": 9522,
            "latest_height": 535196,
            "nodes": {
                "220.75.229.130:3927": [
                    70015,
                    "/Satoshi:0.13.2/",
                    1530858117,
                    13,
                    165277,
                    "220.75.229.130",
                    "Seoul",
                    "KR",
                    37.5985,
                    126.9783,
                    "Asia/Seoul",
                    "AS4766",
                    "Korea Telecom"
                ],
                "192.162.102.68:8333": [
                    70015,
                    "/Satoshi:0.15.1/",
                    1533061934,
                    13,
                    535196,
                    "192.162.102.68",
                    null,
                    "RU",
                    55.7386,
                    37.6068,
                    null,
                    "AS50113",
                    "MediaServicePlus LLC"
                ]        
          }
}
```

So far, this is my code, and JSON objects in Go:

```
type MyJsonName struct {
    LatestHeight int `json:"latest_height"`
    Timestamp    int `json:"timestamp"`
    TotalNodes   int `json:"total_nodes"`
    Nodes        struct {
        Data string
    } `json:"nodes"`
}

func main() {
    jsonFile, err := os.Open("someFile")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    byteValue, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(jsonFile)
    var MyJSONANE MyJsonName
    err = json.Unmarshal(byteValue, &MyJSONANE)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(MyJSONANE)
}
```

This code works great, my issue is the fact that Data in nodes in never populated with the JSON arrays and their contents.

This is the output: `{535196 1533397325 9522 {}}`

Any help adjusting my struct to read in the JSON arrays will be greatly appreciated. I would just like to draw emphasis to the names of the JSON arrays in nodes being unique, and there can be `total_nodes` amount of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go for `map[string]interface{}` to store the nodes data. For unknown json data with dynamic keys Interfaces are best which will help you to store any type of data.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type MyJsonName struct {
    LatestHeight int `json:"latest_height"`
    Timestamp    int `json:"timestamp"`
    TotalNodes   int `json:"total_nodes"`
    Nodes  map[string]interface{}
}

var byteValue string = `{
  "timestamp": 1533397325,
  "total_nodes": 9522,
  "latest_height": 535196,
  "nodes": {
    "220.75.229.130:3927": [
      70015,
      "/Satoshi:0.13.2/",
      1530858117,
      13,
      165277,
      "220.75.229.130",
      "Seoul",
      "KR",
      37.5985,
      126.9783,
      "Asia/Seoul",
      "AS4766",
      "Korea Telecom"
    ],
    "192.162.102.68:8333": [
      70015,
      "/Satoshi:0.15.1/",
      1533061934,
      13,
      535196,
      "192.162.102.68",
      null,
      "RU",
      55.7386,
      37.6068,
      null,
      "AS50113",
      "MediaServicePlus LLC"
    ]
  }
}`

func main() {
    var MyJSONANE MyJsonName
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(byteValue), &MyJSONANE)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v",MyJSONANE)
}
```

Working code on [Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/xLUlT5c4SK7)

To fetch the underlying value from the `interface{}`, you require type assertion for each type. You can go for switch to get the value from interface recursively.

```
func fetchValue(value interface{}) {
    switch value.(type) {
    case string:
        fmt.Printf("%v is an string \n ", value.(string))
    case bool:
        fmt.Printf("%v is bool \n ", value.(bool))
    case float64:
        fmt.Printf("%v is float64 \n ", value.(float64))
    case []interface{}:
        fmt.Printf("%v is a slice of interface \n ", value)
        for _, v := range value.([]interface{}) {
            fetchValue(v)
        }
    case map[string]interface{}:
        fmt.Printf("%v is a map \n ", value)
        for _, v := range value.(map[string]interface{}) {
            fetchValue(v)
        }
    default:
        fmt.Printf("%v is unknown \n ", value)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for, I've been trying to figure this out for hours. Thank you!